# Como reverter um filtro de categorias aplicado com JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html5

No meu site implementei filtro para separar os produtos por categoria e preciso criar um botão que limpe esse filtro e retorne todos os meus produtos. Abaixo o exemplo que usei no meu site.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  var categoria = $(this).attr('data-categoria')
  
  $('.items li').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass(categoria)){
      $(this).hide()
    }else{
      $(this).show()
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn" data-categoria="comida">Comida</button>
<button class="btn" data-categoria="bebida">Bebida</button>

<ul class="items">
  <li class="comida">Arroz</li>
  <li class="comida">Feijao</li>
  <li class="comida">Lasanha</li>
  <li class="bebida">Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve simplesmente acessar todos os elementos `li` e exibí-los:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  var categoria = $(this).attr('data-categoria')
  
  $('.items li').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass(categoria)){
      $(this).hide()
    }else{
      $(this).show()
    }
  })
})

//abaixo, o evento do botão 'limpar' que simplesmente exibe todos os itens'
$("#limpar").on('click', function(){
  $('.items li').each(function(){
    $(this).show();
  })
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn" data-categoria="comida">Comida</button>
<button class="btn" data-categoria="bebida">Bebida</button>
<button class="btn" id="limpar">Limpar filtros</button>

<ul class="items">
  <li class="comida">Arroz</li>
  <li class="comida">Feijao</li>
  <li class="comida">Lasanha</li>
  <li class="bebida">Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Obrigada, Marcos! Eu já tinha feito exatamente isso antes, mas acabei de ver que foi um erro no meu html que não estava permitindo isso. Deu tudo certo :)

Comment: Que bom que deu certo. Queira aceitar a resposta para encerrar a questão. Abraço.

Answer (score -1):

> Toda a tarefa que for realizar na vida possui duas formas. A forma
> correta e  forma equivocada. Então antes de mais nada que o que está
> tentando fazer seria melhor exibido com uma [tabela](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) e não com uma
> [lista não ordenada](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul).

Ao usar a lib [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) tenha em mente que essa ferramenta é um módulo de travessia e manipulação da [árvore DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model). Porque digo isso, porque é frequente encontrar códigos, cursos ou apostilas na internet ensinando a usar o JQuery de forma equivocada.

Módulo de travessia e manipulação de árvore significa que através de um seletor a ferramenta irá percorrer a tal estrutura e irá encontrar dentro de um conjunto de nós aqueles que correspondam a um seletor.

**Geralmente** quando o código itera pelo resultado de uma seleção feita com JQuery é porque houve um equivoco em alguma parte, sejam erros no conceito ou na concepção do significado dos seletores ou na falta de leitura da documentação.

Analisando a sua função de filtragem:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  //A variável categoria recebe o valor do atributo data-categoria do botão que foi pressionado.
  var categoria = $(this).attr('data-categoria')

  //Para cada elemento <li> descendente do elemento cujo a classe é .items...
  $('.items li').each(function(){
    //...se o elemento possuir a classe categoria....
    if(!$(this).hasClass(categoria)){
      $(this).hide()                   //...esconda o elemento.
    //...se o elemento não possuir a classe categoria....
    }else{
      $(this).show()                   //...mostre o elemento.
    }
  })
})
```

É pego o valor um [atributo data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) e colocado em uma variável, depois itera por todos elemento para então saber quem tem ou quem não tem esse atributo para decidir quem será exibido ou não.

Porém existe outra forma de se encarar essa atividade:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  const categoria = $(this).data('categoria');  //A partir valor do atributo data-categoria do botão que foi pressionado obtém o seletor de uma classe.
  $(`.items li${categoria}`).show();            //Aos descendentes do elemento cujo a classe seja itens, exiba todos os elementos <li> cujo a classe esteja armazenada em categoria
  $(`.items li:not(${categoria})`).hide();      //Aos descendentes do elemento cujo a classe seja itens, oculte todos os elementos <li> cujo a classe não esteja armazenada em categoria
});
```

Ou seja se buscarmos a documentação veremos que:

> - [JQuery.show()](https://api.jquery.com/show/): Exibe **todos** os elementos correspondentes a um seletor ou grupo de seletores.
> - [JQuery.hide](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) :Oculta **todos** os elementos correspondentes a um seletor ou grupo de seletores.

O mesmo raciocínio pode ser aplicado a questão principal, que é tornar visível os descendentes `<li>` do elemento cujo a classe é `.items`

```
$('.btn2').on('click', function() {
  $('.items li').show();   //Exiba todo o descendente de .itens cujo sejam um elemento <li>
});
```

Juntando tudo num exemplo:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  const categoria = "." + $(this).data('categoria');
  $(`.items li${categoria}`).show();
  $(`.items li:not(${categoria})`).hide();
});

$('.btn2').on('click', function() {
  $('.items li').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn" data-categoria="comida">Comida</button>
<button class="btn" data-categoria="bebida">Bebida</button>
<button class="btn2">Todos as categorias</button>


<ul class="items">
  <li class="comida">Arroz</li>
  <li class="comida">Feijao</li>
  <li class="comida">Lasanha</li>
  <li class="bebida">Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
```